# Why not getting results from database using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, backend

I am using PDO with OOP. I have a code like this:

```
public function selectOne($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM emps WHERE id = ':id'";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $stmtExec = $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmtExec->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "got results";
    } else {
        echo 'nothing';
    }
}
```

When I try to run this it gives me an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean`

Where am I doing wrong. I am new to Php. Thanks!

Comment: this `':id'` is not valid. should be `:id`.. `prepare()` should be false

Comment: Also `execute` returns a boolean. You should be calling `rowCount()` on `$stmt`.

Comment: @JonStirling, Please tell me then how can i fetch result a(a row) here

Comment: Use `fetch` method on `$stmt`? Read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), in particular, the examples.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the single quotes around the named placeholder `:id`.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM emps WHERE id = :id";`

EDIT:
Also, like correctly stated by @Jon Stirling, `$stmt->execute()` returns a boolean. Method `rowCount()` should be executed on the `PDOStatement` object instead (your `$stmt` variable).

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php